# Android Bundling failed in expo-cli when we run "npm start" or scan expo app in mobile

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-cli

```
    ERROR
00:46
Building JavaScript bundle: error
ERROR
00:46
Unable to resolve module expo-constants from C:\Users\HP\Desktop\React Native\HelloApp\node_modules\expo-asset\build\LocalAssets.js: expo-constants could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
> 1 | import Constants from 'expo-constants';
    |                        ^
  2 | import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
  3 | import { getLocalAssets } from './PlatformUtils';
  4 | // Fast lookup check if assets are available in the local bundle in managed apps
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it safe to assume you have run: `expo install expo-constants`?

If not, do that, and rebuild.

If this is not solving your error try:

- Deleting package-lock and node modules
- rerun `npm install`

If neither of the above solutions work, please provide more information.

Edit: [Constants documentation.](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/constants/)

Comment: Deleting package-lock and node modules
rerun "npm install"

Answer (score 0):

I also had a bundling fail situation. My node js version was 14.o, I upgraded it to the newest version, mine was 18.0. Then it worked fine.